# Django Templates: How to display block of HTML based on a boolean field in model

Tags: python, django, templates, boolean, conditional-statements

Having a strange problem. Let's say, in my Content model:

```
show_in_posts = models.BooleanField()
show_in_news = models.BooleanField()
show_in_updates = models.BooleanField()
```

Then in my `{% for content in contents %}` template:

```
{% if content.show_in_news == 'True' %}
   ....
{% endif %}
```

Can't seem to get the condition to work. It seems `{{ content.show_in_news }}` always evaluates as True, even if the it's set in the Admin panel as unchecked.  I tried no quotes `{% if content.show_in_news == True %}` Also tried all lowercase true, or just `{% if content.show_in_news %}` No luck.

Some other post suggested registering a custom 'filter' but this seems so trivial, should work out of the box?

Assistance much appreciated!

Comment: what `{{ content.show_in_news }}` gives you?

Comment: Per above, seems to be always `True`, even if the checkbox is not checked in the Admin

Comment: Something is definitely wrong. Even my other booleans all print in templates as 'True' when they are definitely set to Off in the DB. I can toggle them in the Admin and save -- they change to red 'stop sign' icons, toggle back & save, back to 'green checkmarks' -- all works fine. I just can't get them to come through via the template as anything other than True. The other types, e.g. CharField, TextArea are showing fine.. Ugh, what gives :(

Comment: can you show us your views?

Comment: Can you show what query you are making to get `contents`?

Comment: Ultimately, the problem wasn't in the code but with the Virtual Machine setup the client has in place. Turns out none of the model or DB changes would take effect unless The Foreman utility was restarted (or, um, something to that effect). Sorry about the "false alarm" and thanks for helping! :)

Answer (score 0):

**You can use for match BooleanField condition:**

```
{% ifequal content.show_in_news True %}
    Your code here
{% endifequal %}
```

**Or like this**

```
{% if content.show_in_news %}
   your code here
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this too.  What was happening was Django's {% if expr %} evaluates true if the expr exists and is not None.  Since the form field itself exists, the conditional always evaluates as true.  Annoying.

You can make it work like you expect by using the value explicitly, like so:

```
{% if content.show_in_news.value %}
```